# How to call a method without an instantiated object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

This is an objective-c question.

I would like to call a method in an object, but there is no instantiation of the object. Is this possible?

The method I want to call is not a class method.

Comment: Can you tell us which method you would like to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you just want a plain-old C function. If you don't want a class method, and you don't want an instance method, that appears to be your only option. Don't be afraid of using C functions in Objective-C. Every technique has its place.

Answer (score 5):

You can't call a method on an object that doesn't exist.  But you can call a method on a **class** even if you have no instantiated objects of that class.  (That's what alloc is in @fbrereton's answer -- a class method).

Class methods are declared and defined with a + instead of a -, are called on the class rather than the instance, and cannot access self or any instance variables in the class (for reasons that should be obvious).

Comment: Would you clal this a "static method" in this language?

Comment: @d03boy in Objective-C we call these "class" methods, but they are functionally equivalent to static methods used in other languages

Comment: They're more than static methods, because object-c class's are real objects just like instances. For example the -[NSArray array] method is dynamic in that it returns an instance of the receiver. [NSMutableArray array] results in a mutable array, but NSMutableArray doesn't have to override that method. It's able to do that by implementing the method like this: "return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease]". That works because 'self' is NSMutableArray in one case, and NSArray in the other. So, in objective-c, you can have polymorphic class methods.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the method is `static` you will not be able to do this. `static` routines in Objective-C will be prepended with a `+`. For example NSObject provides these two routines (among many):

```
+ (id)alloc; // static - an NSObject instance is not required
- (NSString*)description; // nonstatic - an NSObject instance is required
```

One would make the respective calls like so:

```
NSObject* result = [NSObject alloc];
NSString* desc = [result description];
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to nit-pick Chris' terminology, but we don't *call a method on an object* in Objective-C, we *send a message to* an object.  When you send a message, the runtime will look up the appropriate method and call it.  The distinction matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed invoke an instance method without an instance, provided it is functionally a class method (that is, it accesses no instance variables). Here's an example:

```
/*
Compile with:
gcc -framework Foundation inst_method_without_inst.m -o inst_method_without_inst
*/
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject {
}
- (BOOL)doSomethingWithThis:(NSString *)this;
@end

@implementation Foo
- (BOOL)doSomethingWithThis:(NSString *)this {
  NSLog(@"Look, it's this: %@", this);
  return YES;
}
@end

typedef BOOL (*my_sel_t)(id, SEL, NSString *);
int
main(void) {
  Class cls = [Foo class];
  SEL my_sel = @selector(doSomethingWithThis:);
  Method m = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, my_sel);
  // You could also use +[NSObject instanceMethodForSelector:] to get |m|,
  // since |cls| is a kind of NSObject.
  my_sel_t f = (my_sel_t)method_getImplementation(m);
  BOOL result = f(nil, my_sel, @"Hello from an instanceless instance method invocation!");
  NSLog(@"result: %d", (int)result);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You could get it to work even if the instance method accesses instance variables by allocating memory for it to work with (using either `+alloc` or `class_getInstanceSize()` plus `malloc()`) and passing a pointer to that memory as the first `id` argument to the implementation instead of `nil`.

While this is entertaining as an exercise, I can't think of a good reason to not just instantiate the class and use the standard messaging syntax and compiler support. In fact, the only reason we couldn't just do `[(Foo *)nil doSomethingWithThis:@"BOO!"]` here is that `objc_msgSend()` special-cases messages to `nil` with the result that `NO` is returned and nothing happens.

Comment: Upvoting because in additional to being the most technically correct, this was very educational!